# Sphinx - Search query if it contains field value

Tags: search, substring, sphinx, reverse

I want to use Sphinx to search a case like this:

`tags` table:

```
id    text
1     samsung
2     nokia
3     lg
4     lg.com
5     lg.com.uk
...
```

If the query is:

- `I like lg` -> match record `3`
- `I like lg.com` -> match record `4`
- `I like samsung and lg` -> match record `1` and `3`

The idea is that the query should contain the column `text` as its substring. It's like `LIKE` operator in SQL but in reverse order of query and column:

```
select * from tags where 'I like samsung and lg' like concat('%', text, '%')
```

How can I do that in Sphinx?
Thank you.

Comment: have you installed sphinx on your server ?

Comment: I installed it locally with brew ...

Comment: please add your sphinx.conf file here

Comment: I just follow the screencast from Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/120-thinking-sphinx-revised, so as you can see, I don't have anything special. And seems that I'm using all the default settings of Sphinx.